# How would I byteswap a ByteArray?

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm searching for a way how to byteswap a whole ByteArray. For example, if I have following order (example! I have files which have more than 300 bytes in size) like this:

```
80 37 12 40
```

and load it into a ByteArray. How would I swap it to this:

```
37 80 40 12
```

In my project, the usual length is 4 bytes. So it wasn't hard for me to settle this:

```
   public static ushort SwapBytes(ushort x)
   {
       return (ushort)((ushort)((x & 0xff) << 8) | ((x >> 8) & 0xff));
   }

                   byte[] rev = Assembler.Operations.ToByteArray(towrite);
                   byte[] half = new byte[2];
                   byte[] half2 = new byte[2];
                   ushort tt = BitConverter.ToUInt16(rev, 0);
                   tt = SwapBytes(tt);

                   half = BitConverter.GetBytes(tt);

                   Start.fs.Write(half, 0, 2);
```

So, but now how would I do this if I have a binary file which is over 400 bytes big? I can't just do an ushort byteswap. I want to byteswap a whole bytearray like shown above.

Comment: Why convert to ushort and fiddle with bits? just iterate through the array with steps of 2, and swap elements as you go

Comment: What do you want to do if the length of the array is not even but odd?

Comment: @Blorgbeard Because that's how my assembler is built. It works with BitArrays. One for registers, one for instructions. I later append them until I reach 32-bits, then convert them to a bytearray and then do the swap like shown above. However, in this case it doesn't applies anymore as I want to byteswap a whole binary file which is larger than 4 bytes. So I want to byteswap a bytearray. (i read the binary file into a bytearray)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply swap the neighboring bytes in a loop. No need to convert to ushort and fiddle with masks.

```
    static void SwapByteArray(byte[] a)
    {
        // if array is odd we set limit to a.Length - 1.
        int limit = a.Length - (a.Length % 2);
        if (limit < 1) throw  new Exception("array too small to be swapped.");
        for (int i = 0; i < limit - 1; i = i + 2)
        {
            byte temp = a[i];
            a[i] = a[i + 1];
            a[i + 1] = temp;
        }
    }
```